# Tuned Mass Damper

Tags: waves, oscillators, resonance

I was learning about the different applications of resonance and one of them is the tuned mass damper used in buildings.

One thing I am confused about is as to why the mass attached to the building oscillates $180^\circ $ out of phase when in resonance. Is there any mathematical reason behind this or an intuitive way of understanding the concept?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the out of phase wave interferes with the source wave and cancels itself out.

What you don't want, is when the ground moves to create standing waves that go up and down on the building adding energy and eventually breaking things. So a tuned mass damper will remove energy of a particular frequency using the concept of [`mechanical impedance matching`](http://www.physics.mcgill.ca/~guymoore/ph224/notes/lecture18.pdf) borrowed from acoustics and applied to structural mechanics.